# How to share View of an inherited controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a base controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SharedViewExample.Controllers
{
    public class InOutController : Controller
    {
        public string InOut { get; }

        public InOutController(string inOut)
        {
            InOut = inOut;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //return View("~/Views/InOut/Index.cshtml");//Way to solve the problem
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And two inherited controllers:

```
namespace SharedViewExample.Controllers
{
    public class OutController : InOutController
    {
        public OutController():base("Out")
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace SharedViewExample.Controllers
{
    public class InController : InOutController
    {
        public InController() : base("In")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

There is a view file in `~/Views/InOut/Index.cshtml` too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hey! I'm @Html.Raw(((SharedViewExample.Controllers.InOutController)ViewContext.Controller).InOut)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I browse to `http://website/In` or `Out` it throws an exception:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/In/Index.aspx
~/Views/In/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/In/Index.cshtml
~/Views/In/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I think that maybe the use of `return View("~/Views/InOut/Index.cshtml");` is a little bit weird, this should be one of the default paths in this controller. How can I share the View of the inherited controller without passing the view as a parameter? Am I doing something "mvc" wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But some of the actions (like index) will be the same but only changing one thing, so... isn't wrong to repeat code in two controllers and views? Which is the way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I share the View of the inherited controller without passing the view as a parameter? Am I doing something "mvc" wrong?

Yes, you are not using MVC as you are supposed to. So rather than answering *how* you can do this, I'll answer *why* you should not do this.

If you take a look at a [definition for MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), one of the main advantages is loose coupling. The idea is that you can change any Controller, Model or View and you know where the impact is (exactly where you are making the change). In this sense, having a base Controller or a base Model is a bad idea as you end up with tight coupling.

It seems that you are worried about code duplication, and that's perfectly fine. However, not all code duplication is bad duplication. There's useful duplication (like here, where you make it easy to change code later on) and useless duplication (like having some method twice when it could be one method and a parameter). At some point you will end up having so many different checks to see if it's one of the children or the other, that nobody will want to modify that code, not even you.
If you need to share business logic, the way to do this in MVC is by having another layer that your Controllers talk to, namely a services layer.

Also, there's almost never a good reason for doing stuff like this:

```
((SharedViewExample.Controllers.InOutController)ViewContext.Controller)
```

The view is supposed to not even know which Controller is using it (the `ViewContext.Controller` property is needed by the framework, however). If you want to share data from the Controller to the View, use:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Foo = "bar"; // ViewBag is a dynamic type
    var model = new SomeModel { Foo = "bar" };

    return View(model); // the model is strongly typed
}
```

Comment: @rasputino In addition to what Camilo has already stated, I'd advise looking at other components that are part of ASP.NET MVC - it's not just about controllers, models, and views. Reuse can be achieved through things like partial views, display and editor templates, and filters of various types (action, exception, and authorisation). Take some time to implement each of those, and you'll get a much better understanding for how to create a loosely-coupled MVC application that is easy to maintain and extend.